# Using testname as a property in a soapUI groovy script

Tags: properties, groovy, soapui

I'ld like to append test name to the result log.

I see "name" in the "TestCase Properties"

However, when I right click in the groovy script and try to get data, 
I cannot find test name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where you are trying to do this, but if you were to add a new "Groovy script test step" to to test case, adding a log of the name is as easy as:

```
log.info(context.testCase.name)
```

Comment: I was trying to log testdata to an external file and the script below worked..

def today= new Date()
formattedDate = today.format('yyyy-MM-dd-HH')
def file = new File('d:/test/test_'+formattedDate+'.txt')

def testname = context.testCase.name.toUpperCase()

if ((errorCode=='X') && (result=='Y'))
{
 file.append(testname+".errorCode="+errorCode+",result="+result+",PASSED\n")
}
else
{
 file.append(testname+".errorCode="+errorCode+",result="+result+",FAILED\n")
}